# TranslateTransform Not translating lines

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, gridlines

I've been trying to translate a grid (2 arrays of lines) in a canvas via TranslateTransform. However, the lines kind of just shake about and return to their original place and do not translate. Here's the source:

```
    private Point mousePosition;
    private bool CanvasMouseDown;

    private void GraphMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CanvasMouseDown = true;
    }

    private void GraphMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanvasMouseDown)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            var offset = position - mousePosition;
            mousePosition = position;

            for (int i = 0; i < GridLinesHoriz.Length; ++i)
            {
                GridLinesHoriz[i].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < GridLinesVert.Length; ++i)
            {
                GridLinesVert[i].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
            }
        }
    }


    private void GraphMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CanvasMouseDown = false;
    }
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are normalizing the offset as you are handling the `MouseMove` events. The `TranslateTransform` always translates from the **original** location, so you need to compute a running offset that's maintained for the lifetime of the drag operation.

If you change`mousePosition` to class level variable and set that variable when the operation starts (in the `MouseDown` event handler) and stop updating that variable in the `MouseMove` event handler, the lines will start translating the way you expect.

```
point mousePosition;

private void GraphMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CanvasMouseDown = true;
    mousePosition  = e.GetPosition(canvas);
}

private void GraphMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (CanvasMouseDown)
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        var offset = position - mousePosition;

        for (int i = 0; i < GridLinesHoriz.Length; ++i)
        {
            GridLinesHoriz[i].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < GridLinesVert.Length; ++i)
        {
            GridLinesVert[i].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
        }
    }
}
```